# Karate: How to set thread count through Maven Command line?

Tags: karate

I have a TestRunner that looks like bellow:

```
public void myTests() {

    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:...")
            .outputCucumberJson(true)
            .parallel(5);
    Results initialResults = results;
 }
```

I run my test through Maven with the following commmand:
`mvn clean test -Dkarate.options="--tags @TestSuite1 classpath:myfolderoffeatures"`

I want to change the threadcount that is currently set to 5 dynamically based on my testing through Maven

I tried to add -Dkarate.options="--threadcount=10" but it is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

As of now, only tags and the feature / paths are over-ridable via the `karate.options`. What you could do in the mean-time is pass this as a separate environment variable or equivalent, and unpack it from your Java runner. You can write multiple Java "entry points" to serve these needs, for CI or otherwise.

As mentioned in my comment below, this is potentially an area of improvement.

Comment: Would that be correct, because it's not working on Karate 1.3.0 mvn clean test -Dkarate.options="--threads 2 --tags @TestSuite1 classpath:myfolderoffeatures"

Comment: @DevOpsUj I just checked the code and realized that only tags and feature paths are over-ridable, sorry for the confusion. this does seem like a good thing to add, so do consider submitting a PR. the relevant code is here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.0/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Runner.java#L175

Answer (score 0):

We pass the thread count as a argument to the maven command but outside of the karate.options and it works fine for us.

```
  Results results = Runner
            .path("classpath:")
            .outputCucumberJson(true)
            .reportDir(karateOutputPath)
            .parallel(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("threadCount", "1")));
```

In the above code block, threadCount is the property in the maven command, and 1 is the default thread count in the event the system property for threadCount is not present in the maven command.

Here is how its used in the maven command -

```
-Dkarate.env=UAT
-Dtest=RunTestsParallel
-Dkarate.options="--tags @runme12345"
-Dthread.count=5
```